# parameters missing in update action rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is causing this update action to not work? When I debug the controller all instance variables appear to contain the correct data, but i am left with an error `param is missing or the value is empty`

This is the abridged form

```
 = simple_form_for [:admin, @job, @new_delivery] do |f|
    - if jdc.new_record?
      %tr
        %td
         .......
          = f.input :quantity, label: false
       ......
          = f.submit "Add", class: "btn btn-s btn-default"
    - else
      %tr
        %td
          .......
          = jdc.delivery_cost.unit
        %td
       .........
        %td
          = link_to 'Delete', admin_job_job_delivery_cost_path(@job, jdc), method: :delete, class: "btn btn-xs btn-danger"
        %td
          = link_to 'Update', admin_job_job_delivery_cost_path(@job, jdc), method: :patch, class: "btn btn-xs btn-info"
```

I'll add the relevant controller actions below:

```
  def update
    set_job_delivery_cost 
    if @job.present? && @job_delivery_cost.present?
          @job_delivery_cost.update_attributes(job_delivery_cost_params)
      raise @job.inspect
      if @job_delivery_cost.save
        flash[:success]="Changes Saved"
      else
        flash.now[:error]="Check for Errors"
        return render('admin/client_types/edit')
      end
    end
    redirect_to admin_job_job_delivery_costs_path(@job)
  end

  def set_job_delivery_cost
    @job_delivery_cost ||= JobDeliveryCost.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end

  def job_delivery_cost_params
    params.require(:job_delivery_cost).permit!
  end
```

these are the request parameters:

```
{"_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"66fRYMn6/2ges7JU75d5sWUausx8GJvM5dsNpbRxlYQ=", "action"=>"update", "controller"=>"admin/job_delivery_costs", "job_id"=>"53", "id"=>"17"}
```

Server logs...

```
Started PATCH "/admin/jobs/53/job_delivery_costs/17" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-23 18:36:27 +0100
Processing by Admin::JobDeliveryCostsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"66fRYMn6/2ges7JU75d5sWUausx8GJvM5dsNpbRxlYQ=", "job_id"=>"53", "id"=>"17"}
  Job Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `jobs`.* FROM `jobs` WHERE `jobs`.`id` = 53 LIMIT 1
  JobDeliveryCost Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `job_delivery_costs`.* FROM `job_delivery_costs` WHERE `job_delivery_costs`.`id` = 17 LIMIT 1
Completed 500  in 6ms

ActionController::ParameterMissing - param is missing or the value is empty: job_delivery_cost:
```

**delivery cost.rb**

```
# == Schema Information
#

# Table name: delivery_costs
#
#  id            :integer          not null, primary key
#  title         :string(255)
#  unit          :string(255)
#  cost_per_unit :float
#  created_at    :datetime
#  updated_at    :datetime
#

class DeliveryCost < ActiveRecord::Base

  UNIT_DAY='day'
  UNIT_HOUR='hour'
  UNIT_MILE='mile'
  UNITS=[UNIT_DAY,UNIT_HOUR,UNIT_MILE]

  has_many :job_delivery_costs
  has_many :jobs, through: :job_delivery_costs

  validates :cost_per_unit, presence: true
  validates :unit, inclusion: UNITS
  validates :title, presence: true
  before_destroy :survive_if_jobs

  private

  def survive_if_jobs
    jobs.empty?
  end
end
```

**job_delivery_cost.rb**

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: job_delivery_costs
#
#  id               :integer          not null, primary key
#  job_id           :integer
#  delivery_cost_id :integer
#  cost_per_unit    :float
#  quantity         :integer
#  timing           :string(255)
#  created_at       :datetime
#  updated_at       :datetime
#

class JobDeliveryCost < ActiveRecord::Base
  TIMING_INSTALL='install'
  TIMING_BREAKDOWN='breakdown'

  TIMINGS=[TIMING_INSTALL,TIMING_BREAKDOWN]

  belongs_to :delivery_cost
  belongs_to :job
  validates :quantity, presence: true, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to:1}
  validates :timing, inclusion: TIMINGS
  #validates :cost_per_unit, presence: true

validate :validate_cost_per_unit
  validate :check_associates
  # validate :quantity_default
  before_save :init


  private

  def check_associates
    associated_object_exists DeliveryCost, :delivery_cost_id
    associated_object_exists Job, :job_id
  end

  def validate_cost_per_unit
    if delivery_cost and cost_per_unit.blank?
      self.cost_per_unit=delivery_cost.cost_per_unit
    end
    return false if cost_per_unit.blank?
  end

    def init
      if self.quantity.nil?
        self.quantity = 1
      end
    end

end
```

Comment: where does the error occur?

Comment: please show trace log

Comment: where is it? i dont see

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ I added the server logs is that what you need?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ they are there

Answer (score 0):

The error should be in your line `params.require(:job_delivery_cost).permit!`. It's happening because you are not actually sending the form to the update action.

You should change the line:

```
link_to 'Update', admin_job_job_delivery_cost_path(@job, jdc), method: :patch, class: "btn btn-xs btn-info"
```

with an actual submit button, something like this:

```
f.submit 'Update', class: "btn btn-xs btn-info"
```

For that to work, however, you need to change your form action and method to the update action.

Comment: look, I already have a submit button. I tried that and it just adds a new instance each time.

Comment: As I told you in the last sentence, you need to change your form action and method for the update action, probably with something like this: `simple_form_for([:admin, @job, @new_delivery], method: jdc.new_record? ? :post : :patch, url: jdc.new_record? ? admin_job_job_delivery_costs_path(@job) : admin_job_job_delivery_cost_path(@job, jdc)) do |f|`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in that the `job_delivery_cost` field isn't passed via `params`. So I see **three** variants of processing the variable:

1. Add `belongs_to :job_delivery_cost` to `DeliveryCost`, then you have to assign `job_delivery_cost` to either visible input, or hidden one:

   1. Visible real input:

      ```
      = f.input :job_delivery_cost
      ```
   2. Hidden input, so you can't change it explicitly:

      ```
      = f.input :job_delivery_cost, as: hidden, label: false
      ```
2. Try to read the value for the `DeliveryCost` model instance:

   ```
   = f.input :job_delivery_cost, as: hidden, label: false, value_method: :job_delivery_cost
   ```

   and model:

   ```
   class DeliveryCost
   # ...
     def job_delivery_cost
       # ... some code to return job_delivery_cost
     end
   end
   ```
3. Just remove requirement for `job_delivery_cost` field for params, and calculate it based on ids.

Comment: undefined method `job_delivery_cost' for #<JobDeliveryCost:0x00000108344dc0>
doing the above game me this error

Comment: @user3868832 where is the model and db-schema for the table?

Comment: @user3868832 this assgiment `@job_delivery_cost ||= JobDeliveryCost.find_by(id: params[:id])` isn't for model field, just for class instance

Comment: Ok i think i understand. I have added schema and models

Comment: @user3868832 ok, I see two variants, 1. to add `belongs_to :job_delivery_cost` to `DeliveryCost`, or to try get the value from `@job_delivery_cost`

Comment: didnt work I am afraid :( ... spasibo za vashu pomoshch'